# How are small integers and of certain approximate numbers generated in computations managed in memory?

Tags: memory, implementation-details, internals

In the documentation `tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation`, it says:

> Most raw objects such as strings and numbers are allocated separately; however, unique copies are maintained of small integers and of certain approximate numbers generated in computations.

However, I'm not sure what the latter part means. Could anyone explain it?

Comment: Let's say I had `a="hello"` and `b="hello"`. The underlying system could choose to store "hello" in two memory locations and have each variable point to one of those locations, or it could choose to store "hello" once and have each variable point to the same location. What I'm understanding about the paragraph you quote is that for strings, the first approach is taken, but sometimes the system chooses the latter approach in certain situations.

Comment: @lericr Agreed. This is also my guess. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that this refers to something similar to boxed integer caching in Java, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java

Answer (score 6):

Not sure. Maybe this sentence is to be understood in context of the previous sentence:

> For every symbol there is a central symbolic table entry that stores all information about the symbol.

That mean: There is a huge (hash) table for all symbols. Now there are two possibilities: Either the hash table contains a pointer to the actual stored entity (which again might be a complicated data structure allocated on the heap and containing pointers (or hashes?) to its children); or it contains the entity itself. For a thing that is of a native C type and thus "atomic" -- and in the context of *Mathematica*, this will probably be a 64-bit integer (`long long` in C) or a 64-bit float (`double`) -- it would be extremely inefficient if their symbol entry table were a pointer: On modern systems, a pointer is basically a 64-bit integer that stores the memory address. So requesting a simple 64-float stored in the symbol `x` in the *Mathematica* session would entail:

1. Take the hash that belongs to `x` and look it up in the symbol table;
2. the result of the lookup is a pointer to a memory address. So we look up this address to
3. finally retrieve the actual double-value of `x`.

Instead, if just a copy of the double value is stored in the symbol table, one can save one lookup operation (step 2) and one has to shove around half the amount of bytes. That can make a crucial difference when done many, many times.

On the other hand, there are many reasons why not to store the values of more complicated data types in the symbol table. The first reason is size. I imagine that the symbol table should be as small as possible so that it fits into some fast cache. More data in the symbol table means that lookups may take substantially longer. The second reason is that one pointer in the symbol table can point multiple times to the same data; and this allows for *lazy copying*. The following is an example for this;

```
n = 10000000;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
B = A; // AbsoluteTiming // First
B[[1]] = 1.; // AbsoluteTiming // First
B[[2]] = 1.; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0. 
>
> 0.007227
>
> 4.*10^-6

See, apparently copying `A` into `B` costs *nothing*. What actually happens: Just a new symbol table entry for `B` is created with a pointer that points to the same memory block as `A`. Only if we manipulate `B`, then *Mathematica* realizes that `A` and `B` cannot point to the same memory location anymore (because the `A` is supposed to still point to the *same* stored values as before). So now a new array is allocated in memory and the contents of `A` are copied to `B`. And then the first entry of `B` is modified. You see that this first manipulation of `B` takes significantly longer that the second one. This is simply because the second time no copy has to be made.

But lazy copying is worthwhile only if the contents of `A` are significantly larger than a 64-bit pointer because the additional indirection has to be ammortized.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.